# Tool to split PDF pages into separate files

Tags: gratis, osx, windows-7, pdf, file-merging

I am looking for a program that splits and joins PDFs.

By this, I mean:

- (*split*) I can choose *the first x pages* of a PDF and have it output separate PDF files.
- (*join*) I can choose (up to 15) PDF files and have it output a single PDF.

I need it to:

- run on Windows 7 and OSX Snow Leopard (10.6.8) (I don't care if the programs are different ones)
- do the above
- be free

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tool is free:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/

- free (GPLv2), although the pre-compiled versions require a donation be made
- open source
- uses Java for cross platform goodness
- split functionality - page by page, n pages at a time, split by size, by bookmarks
- merge functionality - select a set of PDF files and merge them

It's predecessor was quite competent at merging documents.

Comment: This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. Especially, the answer should point out how the recommended software matches the specific requirements pointed out in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I use PDFTK,  which does precisely what you want - splitting and joining pdf files for free. I use it to extract sections from papers etc or book off etc. Split into individual pages then join the ones I need. https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ There's a windows installer and command line support for osx and Linux (with very simple scripts like `pdftk burst` to split and `pdftk *.pdf cat output.pdf` to join all the pdf files in a directory (that I recall).